# AssertionError in tornado

Tags: python, tornado

I edited this question to show a small example. This demo code is from Introduction to tornado book, and give me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "demo.py", line 25, in <module>
    ui_modules={'Hello', HelloModule}
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1422, in __init__
    self._load_ui_modules(settings.get("ui_modules", {}))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado-3.1.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/web.py", line 1545, in _load_ui_modules
    assert isinstance(modules, dict)
AssertionError
```

---

demo.py

```
import tornado.web
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.options 
import os.path
from tornado.options import define, options
define("port", default=8000, help="run on the given port", type=int)


class HelloHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.render('hello.html')


class HelloModule(tornado.web.UIModule):
    def render(self):
        return '<h1>Hello, world!</h1>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tornado.options.parse_command_line()

    app = tornado.web.Application(
        handlers=[(r'/', HelloHandler)],
        template_path=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),
        ui_modules={'Hello', HelloModule}
    )
    server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
    server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

---

hello.html

```
<html>
<head><title>UI Module Example</title></head>
<body>
{% module Hello() %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ui_modules={'Hello', HelloModule}` is not a `dict`, it's a `set`.

It should be: `ui_modules={'Hello': HelloModule}` (notice the comma was replaced with a colon).

Comment: Thanks. Solves the issue. So, the demo in book is wrong or there is a change in tornado core?

Comment: @loops According to the Tornado github repo, this `assert isinstance(modules...` line has been around for several years. It's most likely a typo in the book.

Answer (score 1):

There is actually an errata for the book located [Here](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/errataunconfirmed.csp?isbn=0636920021292)

Comment: Too bad they don't update the eBook… I mean, it's an eBook!!! Update it OREILLY !!!